# Remove Partitioning feature

Tags: sql-server

How remove Partitioning feature from enterprise version. I delete clustered index and recreated, remove partition schema. But this query show that partitioning is using.

`select * from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features`

Comment: Do you use full text search. Try to query the sys.partition_functions view

Comment: thanks, but how set that is answer :)

Comment: Not sure what your comment means?

Comment: Never mind :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also remove full text search (at least temporarily), as it also creates partitioning functions on Enterprise Edition (in the background)